# Elliptic PDE with mixed first and second-order derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We are given $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}, P)$, a filtered probability space, then $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted right-continuous process.
Consider a function $u(X_t, t)$ that is at least twice differentiable w.r.t. each of its arguments (position $X_t$ and time $t$). I'm looking for a solution to the following (elliptic) PDE:
\begin{equation}
u_t(X_t, t) + t^{a} X_t c_1 u_x(X_t, t) + c_2 u_{xx}(X_t, t) = 1,
\end{equation}
where $a \in (-2,0)$ and $c_1, c_2 > 0$ are arbitrary constants.

I tried to solve it in two different ways using the Laplace transform but my attempts (see below) so far were unsuccessful. I would appreciate if anyone had any advice regarding how to solve such a PDE. Most of the references I found in the literature focus on simpler PDEs with only first-order derivatives or purely second-order derivatives (e.g. the wave $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$). Is there a known method that might be able to solve a PDE with mixed first and second-order derivatives?

**Attempt #1:**
We can apply the Laplace transform w.r.t. $X_t$ (not w.r.t. $t$). We will denote the transform as $\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \{ u(X_t, t) \} := Y(z,t)$ and we will use the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} Y = Y_z$.
Recall the following properties of the Laplace transform:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \{ X_t u_x(X_t, t) \} = - z Y_z(z, t) - Y(z, t) \\
\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \{ u_x(X_t, t) \} = z^2 Y(z, t) \\
\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \{ u_t(X_t, t) \} = Y_t(z,t) \\
\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \{ 1 \} = \frac{1}{z},
\end{align}
under some appropriate initial conditions.

We obtain
\begin{equation}
Y_t(z,t) - t^{a} c_1 (z Y_z(z, t) + Y(z,t)) + c_2 z^2 Y(z, t) = \frac{1}{z},
\end{equation}
with appropriate initial conditions. We apply the Laplace transform once more but w.r.t. $t$ and denote $\mathcal{L}_t \{ Y(z,t) \} = \bar{Y}(z, s)$. Note that $\mathcal{L}\{ t^a \} = a! s^{-a - 1}$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
s\bar{Y}(z,s) - a! s^{-a-1} c_1 (z \bar{Y}_z(z, t) + \bar{Y}(z,s)) + c_2 z^2 \bar{Y}(z, s) = \frac{1}{z s},
\end{equation}

We now get an ODE of the form:
\begin{align}
& s y(s) -  b s^{-a-1} (z \dot{y}(s) + y(s)) + c_2 z^2 y(s) = \frac{1}{z s} \\
\implies & (s - b s^{-a-1} + c_2 z^2 ) y(s) -  a s^{-a-1} z \dot{y}(s) = \frac{1}{z s},
\end{align}
where $b = a! c_1$.

The solution looks quite complicated, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+-+a*x%5Eb+%2B+h*z%5E2+%29+y%28x%29+-++a*x%5Eb*z*y%27%28x%29+%3D+1%2F%28z*x%29. I do not see an easy way to take the inverse Laplace transform.

**Attempt #2:**
Let's try to apply the Laplace transform w.r.t. $t$:
\begin{equation}
s Y(x,s) - a! s^{-a-1} c_1 X_t Y_x(x, s) + c_2 s^2 Y_{xx}(x, s) = \frac{1}{s},
\end{equation}
where we used $\mathcal{L}\{ t^a \} = a! s^{-a - 1}$ for $Re(a)>-1$.\

We obtain a second-order ODE of the form:
\begin{equation}
s y(x) - b x \dot{y}(x) + c_2 s^2 \ddot{y}(x) = \frac{1}{s},
\end{equation}
where $b = a! s^{-a-1} c_1$.

The solution again looks rather complicated, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s+y%28x%29+-+a+x+y%27%28x%29+%2B+h+s%5E2+y%27%27%28x%29+%3D+1%2Fs. I do not see an easy way to take the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Is $X_t$ a function?

Comment: Sorry, should have written this down. Given $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}, P)$, a filtered probability space, then $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted right-continuous process.